# How many axioms does first-order logic need?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, quantifiers

I am confused about the nature of first-order logic's axioms. I want every line of a proof to be a valid sentence, and I want the only rule of inference employed to be *modus ponens*. What axioms do I need?

How, for example, do I prove $(\forall x\forall y P(x,y))\rightarrow(\forall x P(x,x))$? How about $\forall x (Q(x)\rightarrow Q(x))$?

Comment: [Enderton](https://books.google.it/books?id=dVncCl_EtUkC&printsec=frontcover)'s system has three quantifier axioms and *modus ponens* has only inference rule.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking ... but there are systems that use just a handful of axioms and only Modus Ponens, yes. In fact, you can always just conjunct together all those axioms into one big axiom, so that gives you one axiom plus Modus Ponens. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: No, I am asking what axiom schemata are needed to avoid having to write a proof with lines that look like $Q(a)$, with $a$ free.

Comment: It doesn't actually make sense to count theorems, since $A \land B$ could arbitrarily be one or two theorems.

Comment: If your only rule of inference is *modus ponens* (so you don't have substitution) how can you do anything if the valid sentence you want to prove contains a variable which doesn't occur in any of your axioms?